# ccnet Not triggering build when changes are committed to svn

Tags: svn, build-process, cruisecontrol.net

There is a problem with the ccnet. The server is not able to detect modifications even after the changes are committed to SVN. Can anyone help regarding this??

---

**Below is the configuration file for the cruise:**

Project
    http://cruise01/ccnet

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <trunkUrl>http://svn01.com/abc/Project/trunk</trunkUrl>
  <workingDirectory>E:\Project\trunk</workingDirectory>
  <username>abc</username>
  <password>abcd</password>
  <timeout>36000000</timeout>
  <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
  <tagOnSuccess>false</tagOnSuccess>
</sourcecontrol>

<tasks>
  <nant>
    <executable>E:\Project\trunk\tools\Nant\bin\NAnt.exe</executable>
    <buildFile>E:\Project\trunk\dev\build\Project.build</buildFile>
    <baseDirectory>E:\Project\trunk\dev\build</baseDirectory>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>36000000</buildTimeoutSeconds>
    <logger>NAnt.Core.XmlLogger</logger>
    <targetList>
      <target>cruise</target>
    </targetList>
  </nant>
</tasks>
<publishers>
  <merge>
    <files>
      <file>E:\Project\trunk\dev\build\output\*.xml</file>
    </files>
  </merge>
  <xmllogger />
  <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds" cleanUpValue="100" />
</publishers>
```

---

**The ccnet log is as follows :**

2009-03-25 23:13:55,093 [CCNet Server:INFO] Registered channel: tcp
2009-03-25 23:13:55,093 [CCNet Server:INFO] CruiseManager: Listening on url: tcp://10.7.5.98:21234/CruiseManager.rem
2009-03-25 23:13:55,093 [CCNet Server:INFO] Starting CruiseControl.NET Server
2009-03-25 23:13:55,109 [Project:INFO] Starting integrator for project: Project
2009-03-25 23:14:55,046 [Project:INFO] Project: 'Project' is added to queue: 'Project' in position 0.
2009-03-25 23:14:56,093 [Project:INFO] Project: 'Project' is first in queue: 'Project' and shall start integration.
2009-03-25 23:14:56,796 [Project:DEBUG] http://svn01.com/abc/Project/trunk/dev
2009-03-25 23:14:56,812 [Project:DEBUG] Starting process [svn.exe] in working directory [E:\Project\trunk\dev] with arguments [log http://svn01.com/abc/Project/trunk/dev -r "{2009-03-25T17:27:24Z}:{2009-03-25T17:44:56Z}" --verbose --xml --username abc --password abcd --non-interactive --no-auth-cache]
2009-03-25 23:14:56,968 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:14:56,968 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:14:56,968 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:14:56,984 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] tm
2009-03-25 23:14:56,984 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 2009-03-25T17:16:09.658217Z
2009-03-25 23:14:56,984 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:14:56,984 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] /Project/trunk/dev/build/ccnet.config
2009-03-25 23:14:56,984 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:14:56,984 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] fixing build [jerry & tom]
2009-03-25 23:14:56,984 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:14:56,984 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:14:57,078 [Project:DEBUG] http://svn01.com/abc/Project/trunk/tools
2009-03-25 23:14:57,078 [Project:DEBUG] Starting process [svn.exe] in working directory [E:\Project\trunk\tools] with arguments [log http://svn01.com/abc/Project/trunk/tools -r "{2009-03-25T17:27:24Z}:{2009-03-25T17:44:56Z}" --verbose --xml --username abc --password abcd --non-interactive --no-auth-cache]
2009-03-25 23:14:57,250 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:14:57,250 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:14:57,250 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:14:57,359 [Project:DEBUG] No s found under .
2009-03-25 23:14:57,359 [Project:INFO] No modifications detected.
2009-03-25 23:15:57,406 [Project:INFO] Project: 'Project' is added to queue: 'Project' in position 0.
2009-03-25 23:15:57,515 [Project:INFO] Project: 'Project' is first in queue: 'Project' and shall start integration.
2009-03-25 23:15:57,515 [Project:DEBUG] http://svn01.com/abc/Project/trunk/dev
2009-03-25 23:15:57,515 [Project:DEBUG] Starting process [svn.exe] in working directory [E:\Project\trunk\dev] with arguments [log http://svn01.com/abc/Project/trunk/dev -r "{2009-03-25T17:27:24Z}:{2009-03-25T17:45:57Z}" --verbose --xml --username abc --password abcd --non-interactive --no-auth-cache]
2009-03-25 23:15:57,656 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:15:57,656 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:15:57,656 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:15:57,656 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] tm
2009-03-25 23:15:57,656 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 2009-03-25T17:17:54.682187Z
2009-03-25 23:15:57,656 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:15:57,656 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] /Project/trunk/dev/build/ccnet.config
2009-03-25 23:15:57,671 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:15:57,671 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] fixing build [jerry & tom]
2009-03-25 23:15:57,671 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:15:57,671 [1560:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:15:57,765 [Project:DEBUG] http://svn01.com/abc/Project/trunk/tools
2009-03-25 23:15:57,765 [Project:DEBUG] Starting process [svn.exe] in working directory [E:\Project\trunk\tools] with arguments [log http://svn01.com/abc/Project/trunk/tools -r "{2009-03-25T17:27:24Z}:{2009-03-25T17:45:57Z}" --verbose --xml --username abc --password abcd --non-interactive --no-auth-cache]
2009-03-25 23:15:57,921 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:15:57,921 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:15:57,921 [468:DEBUG] [Project svn.exe] 
2009-03-25 23:15:58,031 [Project:DEBUG] No s found under .
2009-03-25 23:15:58,031 [Project:INFO] No modifications detected.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem when our subversion and build server's clocks got out of sync by more than 10 mins. Worth checking to eliminate it as a potential problem.

Comment: Had a similar issue working with a global team. Since they were ahead of our clock, checkins they made wouldn't appear to sometime later in the evening.

Comment: Why aren't your servers running in UTC? And with NTP enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Well obviously CC.NET does not think there are any modifications, so one thing you could do is from the command line issue the svn log command that CC.NET does:

`svn log http://svn01.com/abc/Project/trunk/dev -r "{2009-03-25T17:27:24Z}:{2009-03-25T17:45:57Z}" --verbose --xml --username abc --password abcd --non-interactive --no-auth-cache]`

One thing you will notice is the times in there. If any of the changes you expect to see happened before this period they will not show up. It looks like CC.NET is only looking back into the previous 18 minutes. What if you do a check in while the system is running? DOes it still not recognize it?